# Riemann integral of continuous function is zero implies function is zero

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, 
>   \begin{align}
> \int\limits_{0}^1 f(xt)\,dt=0.
> \end{align}
>   Show that $f\equiv 0$.

I've seen various proofs for this fact, but I've come across one that has me stumped.  The proof is below.

> We have, for any $x\neq 0$,
>   \begin{align}
> \int\limits_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int\limits_{0}^x f(u)\frac{du}{x}
> \end{align}
>   Hence
>   \begin{align}
> \int\limits_{0}^x f(u)\,du = 0 \text{ for all } x\in\mathbb{R}
> \end{align}
>   This shows that
>   \begin{align}
> \dfrac{d}{dx}\int\limits_0^x f(u)\,du=0
> \end{align}
>   for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

How was the variable changed from $x$ to $u$?  Everything past that makes sense.

Comment: The LHS of the first equality is meant to be $$\int_0^1 f(xt)dt $$ else it does not make sense since the RHS is dependent on $x$

Comment: I was going to say that the RHS was meant to be $\int_0^x f(u/x) d u/x.$

Comment: Ah!  That makes sense.  There is a typo in my text then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a change of variables $u=x t$. Then
$$ du = x \, dt \Rightarrow dt = \frac{du}{x}$$
Just remember that as far as integration is concerned $x$ is a constant. Now 
$$
t=0 \Rightarrow u=0, ~~~\text{ and } t=1 \Rightarrow u=x
$$
So
$$
\int_0^1 f(x t) \, dt = \int_0^x f(u) \frac{du}{x} = \frac{1}{x}  \int_0^x f(u) \, du $$
So
$$
\int_0^1 f(x t) \, dt =0 \Rightarrow  \int_0^x f(u) \, du =0 ~~~\forall x \ne 0$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ we have
$$ 
f(x) = 0 ~~~\forall x \ne 0
$$
and by continuity $f(0) = 0$.